# Draggable CCNode Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have managed to make a CCNode draggable with the following code:

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    // start catapult dragging when a touch inside of the catapult arm occurs
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_heroContainer boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog(@"YUM YUM");
    }

    _foodNode.position = touchLocation;
}
```

This works, however if I touch and drag anywhere on the screen it moves the CCNode. How would I make it draggable only if it is being touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `touchMoved:` method is in the scene itself, this is why you get notified independently from where you touch on the screen (and this is correct).

To move your node only when you touch it, try checking in `touchBegan:` that you touching your sprite, and set a flag variable, that you'll later check in `touchMoved:`

Something like this in  `touchBegan:`:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(_foodNode.boundingBox, touchLocation))
 _shouldDragMyNode = YES;
else
 _shouldDragMyNode = NO;
```

And then in `touchMoved`: only change position if `_shouldDragMyNode` is `YES`:

```
if (_shouldDragMyNode)
 _foodNode.position = touchLocation;
```

Sorry, can't test the code right now. But something like this should work.

Comment: Hi Krill. Thanks for the info. I understand what to do though I am struggling to detect the touch on the CCNode. `_foodnode.contentSize` doesnt work nor does `[_spongeNode BoundingBox]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, `contentSize` won't work, because it's a size. Updated the answer. However, the `boundingBox` should work just fine. What is `_foodNode` or `_spongeNode`, if they are sprites, then it should work as is. If they are just CCNode, then you should set their contentSize to some value.